# Maze Hex Loops and Traps 2: Progressive

Tags: mazes, network

Start at 1 (bottom left), and visit all the numbers in order, finishing at 9 (top right).

**Give yourself a special prize if use 257 steps or less!**

I'm still working on all methods... There's some more interesting mazes to come.

[image: A maze]

Comment: I don't seem to know how to attach a text file, otherwise I would add the network if required.  Also, I am not sure I know how best to format such a text.  Advice is always welcome!

Comment: One slightly confusing thing for me here is that the only arrow pointing to 6 comes from 3. Does this mean we have to visit 3 twice (as in 1,2,3,4,5,3,6...)?

Comment: @hexonimo, yes - this puzzle may previsit and revisit checkpoints… It’s something I will try removing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it gets a bit messy, but here is the solution:

> [image]
>
> I have colour coded it to make it easier to follow:
>
> 1 -> 2 = red
> 2 -> 3 = dark blue
> 3 -> 4 = green
> 4 -> 5 = orange
> 5 -> 6 = light blue
> 6 -> 7 = pink
> 7 -> 8 = yellow
> 8 -> 9 = purple

Step count:

> (Split by the colours):
>
> 33 + 19 + 55 + 31 + 30 + 38 + 18 + 33 = **257** steps
>
> Exactly 257 steps as required! I don't believe it is possible in less, unless I am missing something obvious

---

Bit of feedback:

> I like the concept, but this was slightly messy. There is no real easy way to display an answer, and even with colour coding we get cases where 4 lines are parallel and you cant even see the arrows. I would recommend trying to not place checkpoints where you have to go over the same path or it does get messy.
>
> Another confusing thing here, is to visit the numbers in order we actually have to visit them out of order. For instance, to visit 5 we have to pass through 8 and 3 gets passed through multiple times. Would also recommend checkpoints which only should be visited once, and perhaps even enforcing this as a rule.
>
> Keep going though! Mazes are a light, fun challenge to complete.

Comment: A one-turn improvement: from the top of the first tiny red "spike" on the bottom, go right 3, then up-left, right, down-right, right, up-right. This gets you to the point where the blue trail intersects the red in 8 moves instead of 9.

Comment: @Deusovi every turn counts! I've noticed the major issue, I assumed yellow and orange would follow the green path, when there is a much much shorter route, will probably save the 10 - yet to count. Will also add the red improvement though!

Comment: Never mind, not as much saved as I thought it would...

Comment: Hey thanks so much for the feedback - I will def. Looks at not ‘pre-visiting’ checkpoints! It might be hard with this sort of design to avoid re-using tracks though … because the elimination of existing paths will make it too easy… I will think more on this!!

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil, do you want to know which stage you can shave off 2?  You do so well.. I love your coloured lines too.

Comment: @Konchog believe I found it, saved 2 with the purple top left to get 257. I'll admit I was somewhat lazy with some of the stages by assuming they would automatically follow lines in other stages when there were often shorter ways

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil, re. your comments about not sharing tracks, I stand corrected.  Especially when aiming for a particular score.  I'm coming back...